# Problem with undefined variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables

I am trying to run this:

```
function loadApp() {
    var content = getContent("content.xml");
    createMap(content);
}

function getContent(file) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: file,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXml
    });

    function parseXml(xml) {
        var content = [];
        $("element", xml).each(function () {
            var var1 = $(this).children("var1").text(),
            content.push(var1)
        });

        return content;
    }
}

    function createMap(content) {
        alert(content);
    }
```

But when I open the page the alert says my `content` variable is undefined. `getContent()` works fine and gives `content` a string value when I delete `createMap(content);` from `loadApp()`. It seems that `createMap()` is running before `getContent()` and that is why the variable is not defined yet, any idea why this happens and how can I solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you should show us getContent() method.  Maybe it has a callback.

Comment: I guess that your `getContent` function does an asynchronous action (like an Ajax request)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd assume that `getContent()` makes an asynchronous AJAX call. If so, the `createMap()` function is called *before* the response is received.

If that's the case, I'd modify `getContent()` function so that you can pass the `createMap()` function to it, and call it at the right time.

```
function loadApp() {
    getContent( "content.xml", createMap );
}

function getContent( file, fn ) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: file,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXml
    });

    function parseXml(xml) {
        var content = [];
        $("element", xml).each(function () {
            var var1 = $(this).children("var1").text(),
            content.push(var1)
        });
          // Call "fn" instead of returning "content"
        fn( content );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works! but is there another way for my function to run only when the first one is finished and has returned a value?

Comment: @VerizonW: The only way would be to set the ajax request to `async:false`, which is typically a bad idea. Ultimately, your `getContent` function is going to exit long before the AJAX request returns. Because of this, *any* code that relies on the response from the AJAX, must wait to run until the response has been received. If `createMap` is in a scope accessible to `getContent`, you could get by without passing the function, and just calling it directly in `parseXML`. But calling it in `loadApp()` won't work.